# Three.js transparent video texture showing previous frames

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I'm using three.js and am having an issue with a plane with a (transparent .webm) video texture. The video is of a cell rotating in place, and every frame is getting drawn on top of the previous one. Since the video is partially transparent, you can see the previous frames behind the current one. Any suggestions on how to make sure the last frame gets removed before drawing the next one?

Here's the pertinent bit of code: https://gist.github.com/bradsimantel/10168393

And a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wAhl.png

Comment: Are you using CanvasRenderer or WebGLRenderer?

Comment: @mrdoob I'm using WebGLRenderer. I put together a JSFiddle with the .webm in question: jsfiddle.net/4ndDB –

Comment: Oh wait... webm now brings opacity to videos... Yeah, that's a new issue...

Comment: Moving this back to github... https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4656